# Github Forked a project I'm collaborating On in Class

Tags: github, fork, collaboration

I forked by ignorance a project I was working on as a collaborator project for class from github website. The reason was it didn't seem to appear on my repositories list.

The problem is that whenever I remove and clone the project again it appears as forked..

My changes to the project are saved and they are not as big, but I don't want to do pulls to my peers each time I wish to upload some new code.

I've been researching and I've found some solutions:

- Install bitbucket and unfork the project.
- Make a new account on github (which I don't really want to).
- YourSuggestions(); easy/medium

I would appreciate any help! Thank you !

Rubèn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to admin panel on GitHub there's a delete option. You will see the fork listed under your user as your repository. Click on settings and delete it from here.The original project will remain intact.

Comment: Som, I get a warning of bad things happening. I left the project (expecting my peers to add me again, I backed up the project anyway). The name of the project looks like myNickname/NameProject. Is it alright then if I delete the forked project? I'm a little scared of github lol.

Comment: Dont worry. I tried it before suggesting it to you :)  Make sure enter the repo name as <your username>/ repositoryname  .It will work.